# PDOException:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: laravel-5

whenever i run the following command php artisan migrate:install, i will get the following error in my ubuntu 12.04 terminal...
          [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket ' /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

I install laravel 5 in ubuntu 12.04. In my /var/run/mysqld folder, i don't have any mysqld.sock file. Everyone says check out your .env file but i don't have any .env.example file but yes i have app.php, database.php mail.php, cache.php files in my app/config folder.In the whole process i have conclude on thing that their is a problem with connectivity with database because whenever i want to migrate any table in database i will not migrate or not shown in database but i will create table file in my app/controller/http folder. So the problem is table is not displayed in database after i run php artisan migrate command else it will show error above mentioned. So plz help me out. Thankss.......

Comment: you have to create .env file in root, is that what you need to know how to do?

Comment: You need to create a database and configured it in .evn file then you can go, do you know how to do that?

Comment: but when i create .env file i will get the message .env file already exists but i don't know where it is and i searched every folder but don't get .env file.

Comment: your laravel project root

Comment: Edit that file and put your database name, username and password for database

Comment: 'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'lovey'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

Comment: my database name is lovey that i have created in database. username is root

Comment: any update if this is sovled yet

Comment: no even my phpmyadmin is not working. it will show #2002 error..:(..the only problem is mysql connection configuration.

Comment: I really do not know what is going on, but I suggest you to install XAMPP for linux https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html it has web server and mysql and then you can install laravel

Answer (score 8):

1. make sure that MySQL server is up and running, e.g.  telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
2. replace 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1' in env('DB_HOST',

Comment: ysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

Comment: mysql server is not running..:(

Comment: wow 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, i almost gave up on laravel :D

Comment: Well this fixed it for me too osx, is anyone able to explain why this is even a problem? I thought localhost and 127.0.0.1 are synonymous? Local host -> 127.0.0.1 which is a loopback

Comment: mysql treats localhost in special way, which is described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html